# MySQL case when count distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, case

I'm trying to get counts for distinct videos by viewership tier. I have the following table:

```
vid_id  views
1       6
1       10
1       900
2       850
2       125000
3       1010
3       12239
3       150000
```

I tried using this code to get my desired output:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN views < 1000 THEN '< 1K Views'
            WHEN views >= 1000 AND views < 10000 THEN '1K to 10K Views'
            WHEN views >= 10000 AND views < 100000 THEN '10K to 100K Views'
            WHEN views >= 100000 AND views < 1000000 THEN '100K to 1M Views'
            ELSE '1M+ Views'
    END AS tier,
    COUNT(distinct vid_id)
FROM
    test
GROUP BY
    tier
```

Since there are multiple entries for each `vid_id`, I want to group the counts of the videos for each tier using the max number of views for each `vid_id`. So my output should be:

```
tier                COUNT(views)
< 1K Views          1 
100K to 1M Views    2
```

Video #1 reached 900 views max, so it's in the `< 1K Views` tier. Videos 2 and 3 reached 125,000 and 150,000 views, respectively. So they are in the `100K to 1M Views` tier.

Comment: your statement will fail.. group by and select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to proceed in two steps:

- first, use an aggregate subquery to compute the maximum number of views for each movie
- then, spread the above information into tiers

SQL:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN views < 1000 THEN '< 1K Views'
        WHEN views >= 1000 AND views < 10000 THEN '1K to 10K Views'
        WHEN views >= 10000 AND views < 100000 THEN '10K to 100K Views'
        WHEN views >= 100000 AND views < 1000000 THEN '100K to 1M Views'
        ELSE '1M+ Views'
    END AS tier,
    COUNT(*) as distinct_videos
FROM (
    SELECT vid_id, MAX(views) views FROM mytable GROUP BY vid_id
) x
GROUP BY tier
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gArUvAPJCqeYTujjFo5GKt/2)**:

```
| tier             | distinct_videos |
| ---------------- | --------------- |
| 100K to 1M Views | 2               |
| < 1K Views       | 1               |
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve it like this:

- Create a table with the categories that you want, with a min/max value and a description.
- Join that table to get the view category

Example query:

```
select vid_id, views, category_id
from test
join viewgroup on viewgroup.min >= tier.views and viewgroup.max < tier.views
```

You'll get an intermediate result like this:

```
vid_id  views     category_id    tier
1       6         1              < 1K Views 
1       10        1              < 1K Views
1       900       1              < 1K Views
2       850       1              < 1K Views
2       125000    4              100K to 1M Views
3       1010      2              1K to 10K Views
3       12239     3              10K to 100K Views
3       150000    4              100K to 1M Views
```

Now, it'll be easy to get how many you have of those, by creating an outer query:

```
select tier, count(*) from
(
  select vid_id, views, category_id, tier
  from test
  join viewgroup on viewgroup.min >= tier.views and viewgroup.max < tier.views
) 
group by tier
```

Some final notes:

- Instead of having a table you could calculate on the fly like you did in your example.
- If you have a lot of data, don't have `tier` in the inner query. Instead, collect the category_id's, and join the category table for the final result in the outer query. That will be much faster and require less memory for the database server.